# New Site Suggestion

Tags: discussion, humor

[It seems](https://serverfault.com/questions/80831/computer-arcitecture-question-cost-performance-analysis) there's a market for MathematicsFault.com

Any takers?

Mid-term season.

Answer (score 7):

any reason https://mathoverflow.net/ can't work?

Comment: Hah!  Or http://ClassAttendanceFault.com

Comment: They should have bought DivideByZero.com as well.

Comment: The linked question would be more appropriate for basic-arithmetic-help.com.

Comment: Jeff: yes, mathoverflow.net only welcomes research/serious mathematical questions.

Answer (score 6):

There is still a substantial void that needs filling for math questions that are more along the lines of the questions asked on this site, e.g. people asking questions anywhere along the spectrum from simple stuff to moderately complicated but not expert mathematics.

Mathoverflow is for serious/academic/research mathematics and they close down almost all questions below that threshold.