# where to ask questions about networking and logic?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, questions, superuser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions for networking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking)

Hello,

Where can i ask questions about networking, distributed systems and logic ?

Stackoverflow ? or otheroverflows ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have to look elsewhere for logic questions, Possibly http://mathoverflow.com

Comment: @Brad, check out this question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s

Answer (score 1):

[ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

Serverfault is the appropriate place for networking and distributed systems.