# Where can I ask questions for networking?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions regarding

- Networking
- Cisco
- CCNA/CCNP/CCIE
- IP subnetting

Comment: @YOU: I'm actually not entirely certain that *is* a duplicate, although the answers certainly indicate that it is. Regardless, this question seems more straightforward, and Mike's provided a nice answer - I'm closing *that* as a duplicate of *this*...

Comment: @Shog9, I agree with you. May be you could close, reopen this, to make sure close votes are cleared?

Comment: @YOU: or I could just leave a comment, and see if anyone actually bothers to read before voting...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest asking both theoretical network protocol questions and Network Engineering implementation / config questions on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

It's unclear what you mean by ip subnetting, but if you have an ip subnetting question, please consider the existing answers as a possible solution:

- [How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499)
- [How does subnetting work](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) (thanks @Zypher, below)
- [Number of Hosts in a subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219168/number-of-hosts-in-a-subnet)
- [What is a valid subnet address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703090/networking-question-what-is-a-valid-subnet-address)

Answer (score 10):

Most of network-related questions are asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), but some questions are also being asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

From the *About* link of Server Fault:

> Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing
> expert answers related to managing computer systems **in a professional
> capacity**.

And from the *About* link of Super User:

> Super User is a Q&A site for computer
> enthusiasts that’s free.

Answer (score 6):

Oy,

Just to let you know that currently, there's a new beta round of a [Network Engineering Stack Exchange site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). Beta means that it is temporary and will disappear unless it has a decent amount of activity with regards to questions, answers and quality of answers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) graduated from Beta several years ago, It is now the place to ask professional network questions.