# Site for Network Administrators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions for networking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking)

Is there any Stack Exchange site for Cisco CCNA/CCNP/CCIE and Juniper Networks professionals?

That is, for people who configure and support ISP grade WAN, MAN and Corporate Networks.

Comment: Have you tried [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)?

Comment: I know about serverfault, but why should you mix network administrator questions and system administrator questions on one site? Those two are completely different things

Comment: @Troydm: Seriously?

Comment: Why not? I know many ppl who know how to configure cisco router but have no experience in configure unix servers. Those to things are related but why should you mix them up on one site?

Comment: The closest match I could find is this: [Networks](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32668/networks), closed by Robert Cartaino as a duplicate of [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), which seems to second @Jon Seigel's initial comment.

Comment: @Troydm it seems you're misunderstanding something about Stack Exchange.  No one person is an expert in *all* topics on a site.  Winforms is a top tag on Stack Overflow, but I know *literally* nothing about them.  Should I be disallowed from SO?

Comment: @Troydm Perhaps we should have different sites for PHP and C++ programming, we wouldn't want to "mix them up" on one site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it isn't quite as clean as Al suggested... You may wind up dividing your questions between implementation (on Server Fault) and theoretical (Stack Overflow)...

Also see:

1. [Where can I ask questions for networking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking/88308#88308)
2. [How can we improve moderation of IP networking questions on Stack Overflow and associated sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88047/how-can-we-improve-moderation-of-ip-networking-questions-on-so-and-associated-sit)

Answer (score 9):

Seems like [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

> Server Fault is for system
>   administrators and desktop support
>   professionals, people who manage or
>   maintain computers in a professional
>   capacity. If your question is about …
>
> - Servers
> - **Networks**
> - Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace
>
> and it is
>   not about …
>
> - Networking outside the professional workplace
> - Running servers at home for personal use
> - General personal computer troubleshooting
>
> … then you’re in the
>   right place to ask your question!

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 4):

The on-topic place for applied networking questions is Server Fault.

And yes, you're right, there's very little cross-over between installing [Microsoft Exchange Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) and configuring a carrier-grade switch... but you have to draw the line somewhere otherwise you end up with HP-Procurve-exchange, juniper-exchange, extreme-networks-exchange, Cisco-routers-but-not-the-3900/2900/1900-range-because-they-suck-exchange, exchange2003-exchange, sendmail-exchange, c++-exchange, c#-exchange and so on.

And no chance of ever finding the right place to ask your question among all the flame wars about whether or not a new Cisco IOS revision or Exchange Server service pack or .NET version that changes C# around a bit warrants a new Stack Exchange site or not.