# Where can I ask a question regarding mathematical puzzles?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-proposal, site-recommendation, math-se

I thought of MathOverflow.net and Math.StackExchange.com but both of them seem to be for advanced users. I have come up with a simple puzzle, but those sites seem to only support more  innovative topics and discussions.

Do you believe its still OK to post the question there in Math.StackExchange?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to ask *about* a puzzle, or do you want to *post* a puzzle (like code golf)?

Comment: @Bobby, Post a puzzle and get an answer for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) [math.stackexchange.com] is indeed the site for "normal" people. The welcome text says:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for **people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields.** It's 100% free, no registration required.

I'd say that would be the appropriate site to post your question (unless it contains source code and/or is about a specific programming language, then you might consider posting it on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/), instead).

You're correct about Math Overflow being exclusively for professional mathematicians. A question that is deemed "too basic" is [*very* likely to be closed there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s). It is not operated by the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) 2.0 network (the group that runs this site and Mathematics, among others). Their [FAQ](https://mathoverflow.net/faq) says:

> MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level math questions**, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books. Of course, individual questions don't have to be worthy of an article, and they don't have to be about new mathematics. A typical example is, "Can this hypothesis in that theorem be relaxed in this way?"

Answer (score 7):

You *could* ask on the [math.SE's meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/); it perhaps depends on the nature of the puzzle itself. From the FAQ/about (emphasis mine):

> Mathematics - Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about:
>
> - Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems
> - Hints on mathematical problems (but please read our FAQ about homework questions)
> - History and development of mathematics
> - **Solving mathematical puzzles**
> - Software that mathematicians use

So maybe it isn't a *bad* fit - but like I say; maybe ask on the math meta whether it is a "fit", and accept that *maybe* the answer is "no".

Answer (score 5):

This kind of question is acceptable on [**Puzzling Stack Exchange**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), a site that did not exist when the question was originally asked. As the name suggests, this is a site focused on puzzles. We accept both questions which *are* puzzles and questions which are *about* puzzles (though the site started off as just the latter). Thus the clarification in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90603/where-can-i-ask-a-question-regarding-mathematical-puzzles#comment239582_90603) about what you want to do:

> Post a puzzle and get an answer for that

means I believe this to likely be on-topic.

**Two common reasons for questions such as this to be off-topic**

While we do accept questions where someone asks for the solution to a puzzle *which they have not created*, in such cases it is required to [provide attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6407). Attribution could look like a link to where the puzzle can be found, the name of a book the puzzle was taken from, etc.. This is to prevent people trying to cheat in e.g. a math competition.

Math puzzles must also keep in mind the [Math puzzle vs. Math problem](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784) policy. The (admittedly subjective) requirements to be on-topic are at least one, preferably multiple, of the below:

> - Clever or elegant solution, often an "aha" moment
> - Unexpected problem statement.
> - Unexpected or counterintuitive result.

This is to prevent questions such as "Solve for x: 2x+3=7." - which is clearly not a puzzle - while allowing interesting puzzles which make use of mathematics. Browse some [highly-voted non-closed math puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmathematics%5d%20closed%3ano) and some [closed math puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmathematics%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) to understand what we're looking for.

Happy puzzling!